# Can I connect a database to android app using Apache instead of Redis Sever if I already have a .sql database?

Tags: android, mysql, node.js, apache, redis

I'm trying to run this android restaurant project from github: https://github.com/gaodayue/RESTaurant_android

and the frontend and backend for the project requires Node.js, Redis and MySQL: https://github.com/gaodayue/RESTaurant_backend
I'm not familiar with Redis or Node.js at all, so how do I access and connect the databases stored in the ddl.sql file to app in some other way? Is it possible with an Apache Server?

Answer (score 0):

well, i think you are using REST service, if you want to use that from apache server, you have to create a REST API for apache, can be made in PHP for example

Comment: How do I create a REST API for apache?

Comment: you need knowledge, here is a link that can help you: http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/laravel-5-rest-api                                       , but if you dont code in php its gonna take some time, you can make a restful service with another tool, you can use Spring boot, to create that its easies, but is for Java